# Does Java recompile every file every time?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm compiling a sample Android application that makes use of the `symja` library, which itself uses the following libraries by directly including them in `src`:

```
com.google.common.*
edu.js.*
org.apache.commons.math*
org.matheclipse.*
```

Building this application takes about 1:30 minutes and 2.8 GB of RAM. I think that's fine with  something as complicated as a Computer Algebra System library.

Unfortunately that's not only the first time.

When I change even just one line of code in one of the few .java files that make up the actual app and not the libraries, I have to wait 1:30 minutes again.

This is the only notification of progress I get during that time:

http://puu.sh/sBr5

I checked the file modification dates, and in that time only the .apk and .dex file are updated. What could be making it take that long?

[Project directory (zip)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2399384/SymjaDroid.zip)

Comment: No, this is not how it works--it should not be recompiling every file--are you sure that it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse Java builder is incremental (see "Sidebar: the Java Builder" on [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html)), so it shouldn't be having to rebuild your entire project every time.  Something unusual must be going on if it is indeed recompiling every single file.

Comment: It turned out to be ye ol' dex bug, which means dex translates every .class file every single build.

Answer (score 2):

Just deselect "build automatically" in the menu under Project.

Comment: Assuming he's using eclipse :)

Comment: @JimBarrows the OP tagged the question "eclipse", so I'd say it's a fairly safe assumption :)

Comment: This didn't solve the problem. I'm basically staring at this for 1 minute every time I run the program on my phone after changing something in the code. http://puu.sh/sBr5 If I change any of the other resources, I don't have to wait nearly as long, so I'm sure it's something with the code.